# If $z$ is any complex number satisfying $|z-2|=1,$ then show that $\sin(\arg z)=\frac{(z-1)(z-3)i}{2|z|(2-z)}$

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z$ is any complex number satisfying $|z-2|=1,$ then show that $\sin(\arg z)=\frac{(z-1)(z-3)i}{2|z|(2-z)}$
I let $z-2=e^{i\theta}$ because $z-2$ is a unimodular complex number.
$z=2+e^{i\theta}$
Argument of $z=\theta$
We need to prove that $\sin\theta=\frac{(z-1)(z-3)i}{2|z|(2-z)}=\frac{(e^{i\theta}-1)(e^{i\theta}+1)i}{-2e^{i\theta}|2+e^{i\theta}|}$
$=\frac{(e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta})}{2i|2+e^{i\theta}|}$
Put $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ and $e^{-i\theta}=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta$
$=\frac{\sin\theta}{|2+\cos\theta+i\sin\theta|}$
$=\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{(2+\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}}$
But the denominator does not simplify to $1$.I dont know where have i gone wrong?Can you help me?

Comment: The argument of $z$ isn't arg$(e^{i\theta})$; it's arg$(2+e^{i\theta})$, which is something else.

Comment: What should it be then?

Comment: I think take $x+iy=z$ tgen simplify mod and then continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$z=\cos t+2+i\sin t$$

As $(z-1)(z-3)=(z-2)^2-1,$

$$\dfrac{(z-1)(z-3)}{|z|(2-z)}=\dfrac{(\cos t+i\sin t)^2-1}{-(\cos t+i\sin t)\sqrt{(\cos t+2)^2+\sin^2t}}=\dfrac{-2\sin t(\cos t+i\sin t)}{-(\cos t+i\sin t)\sqrt{(\cos t+2)^2+\sin^2t}}=\cdots$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Same problem with this method also,denominator does not simplify to $1$.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia, Why it has to be?

Comment: Because we have to prove RHS as $\sin\theta$.

Comment: @VinodKumarPunia, As $$\arctan(z)=\dfrac{\sin t}{\cos t+2}$$  $$\sin\arctan z=\dfrac{\sin t}{\sqrt{(\cos t+2)^2+\sin^2t}}$$ as well

Comment: Yes yes i realised it.I plotted it on the graph paper.Thank you.